# Microsoft graph call from Sharepoint Url

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Suppose that I have the two following *urls*:

`https://MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/DevTeam/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

`https://MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/DevTeam/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=VIEW_ID&id=%2Fsites%2FDevTeam%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral`

How do I "convert" them into graph api calls? Eg:

1. Only having the host name (`MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com`) and the site name (`DevTeam`), how do I list all the root documents of the site drive with a graph api call?
2. Only having the host name (`MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com`), the site name (`DevTeam`), an ID i'm not sure what corresponds to but that I can read in the url (`VIEW_ID`) and a path (`DevTeam/Shared Documents/General`), how di I list all the files in DevTeam/Shared Documents/General with a graph api call?

Answer (score 0):

The first URL is for your site's document library. The 2nd URL is for the `\General` folder in that library.

To access a site given its URL, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http In your case, the API call would be

```
GET /sites/MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com:dev/
```

To access the default document library ("drive") for a site, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http In your case, the API call would be

```
GET /sites/MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com:dev/drive
```

To list the files in a folder of a drive, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http In your case, the API call would be

```
GET /sites/MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com:dev/drive/root:/general:/children
```